# Export Sphinx index data to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Is it possible to export sphinx index data to SQL so that it can be imported into the original table? A table was dropped in a dev environment and we neglected to make a backup. Its for vBulletin. Need to recover the pm and pmtext tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation:

> Note that the original contents of the fields are not stored in the Sphinx index. The text that you send to Sphinx gets processed, and a full-text index (a special data structure that enables quick searches for a keyword) gets built from that text. But the original text contents are then simply discarded. Sphinx assumes that you store those contents elsewhere anyway.

Sorry.